# Meaning of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}_+$

Tags: notation

I am reading the book, "Introduction to Embedded Systems, a Cyber-Physical Systems Approach" written by Edward Ashford Lee and Sanjit Arunkumar Seshia, and there is a definition that I cannot understand at page 46:

> As in Section 2.2, the Integrator actor of Figure 3.2 can be modeled by a function of the form
> $$I_i : \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}_+}\to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}_+},$$
> which can also be written
> $$I_i : (\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}) \to (\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}).$$

Does the $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}_+$ plus means exponentiation this context?

Comment: $A^B$ means the functions from $A$ to $B$. So $I_i$ will take a function that maps the positivie reals to the reals and "transform" it into another function that maps the positive reals to the reals. For example if $f(x)=\ln(x)$ and $g(x)=\ln(3x)$,you can define a function $I_i(f)=g$.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is correct.

Comment: @Bernard I think you meant "from $B$ to $A$".

Comment: YES, of course. Thank you.